# How to model this item structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, shopping-cart

Sorry if this is a duplicate.

What I want to model is a shopping cart that adds items to it (and presumably later creates an order). There are two main different item types. Stock types which have stock, and generic types which don't have any stock. Stock items can only be added if there's enough stock, otherwise it's not added. There would be a base class that have the shared properties between both kinds of items.

My plan initially was before adding the item to the shopping cart, check if it's a stock item and if so do the necessary stock checks. Otherwise just add the item to the cart.

A co-worker suggested a different approach, which wouldn't need to test the type of item; instead, the base class method would have "hasEnoughStock()" method. Stock items would have the method overridden to do real stock checks, non-stock items would simply return some true value (i.e. they always have enough stock). I think my co-worker has the better approach; however to me it feels a little funny having a function to check stock for an item which in reality doesn't have any real stock.

What I would like to ask is which is the correct approach from an OO point of view (or perhaps there are different approaches).

We're planning to do this in C# if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks to both of you ... just one of those things where the name set me down the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think, the approach with a common function in the base class is correct.
When you have doubts about the name `hasEnoughStock()`, what about a function called `canAddToCart()`?`

The non stock item class will just return true or make some other checks, the stock item class will call a private function called `hasEnoughStock()` like this:

```
public class NonStockItem : Item {
    public override bool canAddToCart () {
        return true;
    }
}


public class StockItem : Item {
    public override bool canAddToCart () {
        return haveEnoughStock();
    }

    private bool haveEnoughStock () {
        return ... doStockCheckHere;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it.

Lets say you have a class WashingMachine. The duty of the WashingMachine object is to wash clothes.  It is not the duty of the WashingMachine to calculate the tax, check if it is out of stock, or in stock.

Calculating tax is the duty of the Billing, and check if it out of stock is the duty of something else.

In the same way, I think it is not the duty of the Item, to decide wether it is instock item or out of stockItem. It should be delegated to **someother** in this case it may be `Warehouse`class or something who determines the type, and decides to add it or not.

```
Class Item
{

}

//Lack of creativity, I just named it as Manager. You can come up with more appropriate name,
Class Manager
{
   //Determine weather the item is with stock or without stock.


 }

 Class Shoppingcart
 {
     //Instantiate Manager.
     //Invoke the method which determines stock or out of stock.

 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate in some way how that would work in terms of code because I can't quite see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your co-worker's approach seems reasonable - if it helps you can think of the non-stock item (say e-book for example) as virtual stock. It is just semantics, but you can call your property/method what you like, it doesn't have to be "hasEnoughStock" - it could be "IsAvaialble" or "ValidItem". whatever seems most logical to you.